# sqlite unique index multiple columns any combination

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, indexing, constraints

I have a table of locations and distances.  The distance between A and B is the same as the distance between B and A.  Is it possible to add a unique constraint to a table such that the columns when Trying to insert the combination 'B and A' fails if 'A and B' have already been inserted

```
INSERT INTO locTbl VALUES ('A', B', 100.0);  //Good to insert

loc1 | loc2 | dist
-----+------+-----
A     B      100.0

INSERT INTO locTable VALUES('B','A',100.0); //Produce an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CHECK constraint must not contain a subquery, so you have to do this with a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER locTbl_loc12_unique
BEFORE INSERT ON locTbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "loc2/loc1 already exists")
    FROM locTbl
    WHERE loc1 = NEW.loc2
      AND loc2 = NEW.loc1;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just require loc1<=loc2 (or >=)

```
create table locTbl (
   loc1 text,
   loc2 text,
   dist integer,
   constraint c check(loc1<=loc2)
);
```